# Determine the boundedness and monotonicity of the sequence with $a_n$ for $\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^3 +1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine the boundedness and monotonicity of the sequence with $a_n$ for $\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^3 +1}}$

For this question for all nonnegative real numbers, this is monotonic correct? How does one demonstrate this?

It's also unbounded since $n^2$ $\gt$ $n^\frac{3}{2} +1$ for all nonnegative real numbers $\gt$ 1

Is that correct? How could I explain this more concretely?

Comment: Here is a hint: you need to show that $a_{n+1}> a_n$. Because all terms are positive, you can square the inequality and prove instead that $a_{n+1}^2 > a_n^2$. Cross multiply the inequality between the two fractions, expand and simplify